# Proton-CEP Receiving events API NGSI/XML NullPointerException

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have trouble sending NGSI/XML formatted events to my Proton-CEP GE. The use case is that I will need Orion to send events to CEP.

Orion is configured to send events to Proton, which are correctly received. However, Proton reports `NullPointerException` when it receives them.

The output from catalina.out is:

```
Nov 12, 2015 7:30:27 PM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.providers.EventXmlNgsiMessageReader readFrom
INFO: started event message body reader
Nov 12, 2015 7:30:27 PM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.providers.EventXmlNgsiMessageReader readFrom
INFO: Event: DeviceContextUpdate
Nov 12, 2015 7:30:27 PM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.providers.EventXmlNgsiMessageReader readFrom
SEVERE: Could not parse XML NGSI event java.lang.NullPointerException, reason: null
 last attribute name: null last value: null
Nov 12, 2015 7:30:27 PM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.providers.EventXmlNgsiMessageReader readFrom
INFO: finished event message body reader
Nov 12, 2015 7:30:27 PM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.resources.EventResource submitNewEvent
INFO: starting submitNewEvent
Nov 12, 2015 7:30:27 PM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.resources.EventResource submitNewEvent
SEVERE: Could not send event, reason: java.lang.NullPointerException, message: null
```

Sending the following JSON event directly to CEP works:

```
{"Name": "Device", "datacount5": "10", "lastupdate": "12/11/2015-17:09:08"}

INFO: starting submitNewEvent
Nov 12, 2015 7:31:39 PM com.ibm.hrl.proton.router.EventRouter routeTimedObject
INFO: routeTimedObject: forwarding event Device; EventId=32314f63-75d3-489f-9d8d-dbd0ba4a42b8; Chronon=null; DetectionTime=1447353099831; Name=Device; Certainty=0.0; Cost=0.0; lastupdate=1447344548000; EventSource=; OccurrenceTime=null; datacount5=10; Annotation=; Duration=0.0; ExpirationTime=null;  to consumer...
Nov 12, 2015 7:31:39 PM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.resources.EventResource submitNewEvent
INFO: events sent to proton runtime...
```

However, sending it in NGSI/XML produced a NullPointer Exception as above. The sent message is:

```
<notifyContextRequest>
  <subscriptionId>51a60c7a286043f73ce9606c</subscriptionId>
  <originator>localhost</originator>
  <contextResponseList>
    <contextElementResponse>
      <contextElement>
        <entityId type="Device" isPattern="false">
          <id>Device.imei2</id>
        </entityId>
        <contextAttributeList>
          <contextAttribute>
            <name>datacount5</name>
            <contextValue>5</contextValue>
          </contextAttribute>
        </contextAttributeList>
      </contextElement>
      <statusCode>
        <code>200</code>
        <reasonPhrase>OK</reasonPhrase>
      </statusCode>
    </contextElementResponse>
  </contextResponseList>
</notifyContextRequest>
```

Note: I have also tried sending the message found in [the documentation](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Complex_Event_Processing_Open_RESTful_API_Specification#Receiving_Events_API) and I get the same NullPointerException, so I know it is not a XML formatting issue.

What is the reason phqp the JSON objects are accepted, but the NGSI/XML fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When NGSI/xml messages are parsed by the CEP, there is a translation process between the NGSI message and the CEP input event.

The matching input event defined in the CEP must have the name `<entity type>ContextUpdate` which is `DeviceContextUpdate` in your case

This input event must have the following attributes:

- entityId – of type String. This attribute holds the entityId value provided in the message
- entityType – of type String. This attributes holds the entity type provided in the message

Details and example can be found in the [CEP user guide appendix](https://github.com/ishkin/Proton/blob/master/documentation/ProtonUserGuidev4.4.1.pdf)

Comment: Thank you @Tal Haham, I have discovered this 15 minutes ago. I wish they marked this more clearly in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Event name is different when sending an Event using the JSON REST than the XML/NGSI format.

When using JSON, the event name is exactly as described in the JSON object

```
{"Name": "Device", "datacount5": "10"}
```

so, `Device`.

In the case of XML/NGSI, even if the entity type is also set to `Device` like this:

```
<entityId type="Device" isPattern="false">
  <id>Device.imei2</id>
</entityId>
```

The Event name is converted to `DeviceContextUpdate`.

This information is provided (hidden?) in the [Appendix A of the user documentation](https://github.com/ishkin/Proton/blob/master/documentation/ProtonUserGuide-FI-WAREv4.4.1.md#getting-events-from-the-context-broker).